# Random Images, Random Text show after Refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these syntax to display random text and image after refreshing the browser.  Everything works fine.  Please take a look.

JavaScript

```
var quotes=new Array();
quotes[0] = "text1";
quotes[1] = "Text2";
quotes[2] = "text3";
quotes[3] = "text4";

var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));

function showquote(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[whichquote].style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote];

}
showquote();
```

HTML

```
<div id="quote"></div>
<div>
    <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1" />
     <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2" />
     <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3" />
       <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    display: none;
}
```

But later on, I add many more `<img scr.../>` tags (which are not related to the purpose of this JavaScript) on different places in the page, then the random images didn't show up.

I try a different way by changing document.getElementById to document.getElementByClassName as the syntax below, it doesn't work.

```
var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));

function showquote(){
    document.getElementByClass('image')[whichquote].style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote];

}
showquote();
```

Then, I try to add an id="imgShow" in each `<img..>` tag

```
<div id="quote"></div>
    <div>
        <img id="imgShow" class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1" />
         <img id="imgShow" class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2" />
         <img id="imgShow" class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3" />
         <img id="imgShow" class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4" />
    </div>
```

And instead of `document.getElementsByTagName`, I change to `document.getElementById` as below, but the random images don't show, either.

Any idea?

```
var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));

function showquote(){
    document.getElementById('imgShow')[whichquote].style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote];

}
showquote();
```

I also try to distinguish the random `<img src>` tags with other `<img src>` tags inside the page by adding an ID for the parent `<div>`, then trying to call only the `<img>` inside that ID, but no success.

HTML

```
<div id="quote"></div>
<div id="RefreshImg">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1" />
     <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2" />
     <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3" />
     <img class="image" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4" />
 </div>
```

JavaScript

```
var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));

function showquote(){
    document.getElementById('RefreshImg img')[whichquote].style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote];

}
showquote();
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: class name seems like the way to go. note that the code you provided you put `getElementByClass` where I think you wanted `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Each element is supposed to have a unique ID, by the way.

Comment: If you create your array like `['text1','text2','text3','text4']` you save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go about it in a slightly different way.

HTML:

```
<div id='quote'></div>
<img id='quote-img'>
<!-- by giving the img tag an id, we can leave other img tags throughout
     the document untouched when we set our random image -->
```

JavsScript:

```
var quotes = [
    {img: "http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1", quote: "text1"},
    {img: "http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2", quote: "text2"},
    {img: "http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3", quote: "text3"},
    {img: "http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4", quote: "text4"}
    /*
       I've moved the quotes and matching images into objects inside an array
       That way, we keep stuff neatly together, and it allows for a great deal
       of flexibility when it comes to adding or removing stuff.
    */
];

function showquote() {
    var q = quotes.length;
    // var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));      // Logical error...
    var whichquote=quote[Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1))];  // ... fixed.

    /*
       I've moved the quote selection logic into the showquote function.
       Again, it allows for more flexibilty: now you could theoretically call
       showquote multiple times (maybe through setTimeout for example) and
       end up with a different random quote+image each time.
    */

    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = whichquote.quote;
    document.getElementById('quote-img').src = whichquote.img;
 };
 showquote();
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew!  I try to replace your code, but `quote-img` is undefined and `quote` is undefined, too.  That means no image and no text show up.  I wonder how comes

Comment: Well, you do call showquote() only after the document's been loaded, right? The document.getElementById() calls will fail if the HTML parser hasn't had a chance to see the div and img tags yet...

Comment: Yes it is right and I believe it is a right approach, but there is missing something.

Comment: Found it. Change `var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));` to `var whichquote=quotes[Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1))];`. Bonus points: explain what the error was and how it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var quotes = [];
quotes[0] = "text1";
quotes[1] = "Text2";
quotes[2] = "text3";
quotes[3] = "text4";

var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote = Math.floor(Math.random()*q);

function showquote(){
    document.getElementById('img'+whichquote).style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote];
}
showquote();

<div id="quote"></div>
<div>
 <img id="img0" style="display:none;" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=1" />
 <img id="img1" style="display:none;" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=2" />
 <img id="img2" style="display:none;" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=3" />
 <img id="img3" style="display:none;" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x50&text=4" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is hardly a better solution. Whenever you add more quotes you have to add and id. You can make it more flexible using a common class and targeting elements by index.

Comment: It's not better, but I assumed he/she is looking for "simple and similar to mine" rather than "optimal and clean".

Comment: Thank you, Eldorado.  I try to replace your code, nothing shows up! I wonder why?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to edit the element ID in the showquote() function - replace it to getElementById('img'+whichquote) and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, Eldorado. but sorry, it doesn't work.  In `<img>` tags, we have id="img0", id="img1", id="img2" and then id="img3", but javascript calls ID- 'img' as the code: getElementById('img'+whichquote), I don't think it would match

Comment: Well you can see it here that it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/4tj6r/51/ ; Not that it matters now, just for info. When calling getElementById(), the parameter is 'img0' up to 'img3'.